# PHP: How can I generate a hmac SHA1 signature of a string?

Tags: php, hmac, hmacsha1

I am trying to connect to an API using PHP and need the correct signature.

**Their documentation verbatim:**

> The command string needs to hashed using HMAC SHA-1 hashing algorithm
>   against the API secret key. The resulting byte array should be Base64
>   encoded in UTF-8 format so that it can be passed via http.
>
> To generate the signature you have to lower case the complete list of
>   request parameters and sort them alphabetically via the field for each
>   field-value pair. The resulting string to sign from the previous
>   example with a secret key VDaACYb0LV9eNjTetIOElcVQkvJck_J_QljX would
>   be:
>
> apikey=mivr6x7u6bn_sdahobpjnejpgest35exqjb8cg20&command=deployvirtualmachine&serviceofferingid=21624abb-764e-4def-81d7-9fc54b5957fb&templateid=54c83a5e-c548-4d91-8b14-5cf2d4c081ee&zoneid=1128bd56-b4d9-4ac6-a7b9-c715b187ce11
>
> Resulting in a signature value of:
>
> ahlpA6J1Fq6OYI1HFrMSGgBt0WY%3D

**Example Attempt:**

```
$string = 'apikey=mivr6x7u6bn_sdahobpjnejpgest35exqjb8cg20&command=deployvirtualmachine&serviceofferingid=21624abb-764e-4def-81d7-9fc54b5957fb&templateid=54c83a5e-c548-4d91-8b14-5cf2d4c081ee&zoneid=1128bd56-b4d9-4ac6-a7b9-c715b187ce11
';
$string = utf8_encode(strtolower($string));
$key = 'VDaACYb0LV9eNjTetIOElcVQkvJck_J_QljX';
$signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $string , $key);
print 'SIGNATURE:'.$signature.'<br>';
if($signature=='ahlpA6J1Fq6OYI1HFrMSGgBt0WY%3D'){
    print 'SUCCESS';
}else{
    print 'FAIL';
}
```

**RESULT:** 9077d90baa7ab8913811b64a50814b640dce60eb

Suppose To Be: ahlpA6J1Fq6OYI1HFrMSGgBt0WY%3D

**QUESTION:** Result does NOT match their documentation. Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your signature should be generated like this:

```
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $string , $key, true)));
```

The last parameter's default value is `false`. Then it'll return a hex-coded string instead of raw bytes. Then you have to base64_encode the bytes as stated in the documentation. And then you'll have to urlencode it as the `=` has to be transformed

Comment: This is definitely closer. The signature returned is the same length as the documentation example but it doesnt match. Now i get kHfZC6p6uJE4EbZKUIFLZA3OYOs%3D instead of expected ahlpA6J1Fq6OYI1HFrMSGgBt0WY%3D

Comment: remove the linebreak in your string

Answer (score 0):

You should set `$raw_output = TRUE` in `hash_hmac()`.
Also you should use `strcmp()` instead of `==`

So the actual code will be

```
$string = 'apikey=mivr6x7u6bn_sdahobpjnejpgest35exqjb8cg20&command=deployvirtualmachine&serviceofferingid=21624abb-764e-4def-81d7-9fc54b5957fb&templateid=54c83a5e-c548-4d91-8b14-5cf2d4c081ee&zoneid=1128bd56-b4d9-4ac6-a7b9-c715b187ce11
';
$string = utf8_encode(strtolower($string));
$key = 'VDaACYb0LV9eNjTetIOElcVQkvJck_J_QljX';
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $string , $key, $raw_output=TRUE))); 
print 'SIGNATURE:'.$signature.'<br>';
if(strcmp($signature,'ahlpA6J1Fq6OYI1HFrMSGgBt0WY%3D'))
{
    print 'SUCCESS';
}
else
{
    print 'FAIL';
}
```